# In SQL , how do I JOIN a column that is usually null so that the data is still retrieved?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad, coalesce, nvl

I want to incorporate a new column into a working SQL query.

However,   it causes the whole query return nothing at all(because the column is mostly null  in the database) .

Here's my pared-down code so far :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT     submittedRow.PERFORMED_DATE as "submitted",     
                     supervisorRow.PERFORMED_DATE as "superv",     
                   /* coalesce(sodRow.PERFORMED_DATE, TO_DATE('2000/07/07', 'YYYY/MM/DD') ) */ null AS "SOD"    


       hhs_umx_resp_activity submittedRow
       join hhs_umx_resp_activity supervisorRow ON supervisorRow.reg_request_id =  configRow.reg_request_id
       /* join hhs_umx_resp_activity sodRow  ON sodRow.reg_request_id = approvedRow.reg_request_id */ 


        left join  HHS_UMX_REG_REQUESTS hurr  on hurr.reg_request_id = hur.reg_request_id
               WHERE


               and supervisorRow.ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'ASP'

               AND submittedRow.activity_result_code = 'SBT'

           /*  AND sodRow.activity_result_code = 'ASD'*/

                and hur.REG_REQUEST_ID  IN ('262097')
```

The column that is mostly null, which I want to add in, is `sodRow`  ( that's why the code `AND sodRow.activity_result_code = 'ASD'` is commented ).

Whenever I put back the extra join for `sodRow` , it just nulls out everything and I get no results at all. But I want it to work like a `NVL` or `COALESCE`, where it *only* displays that column if it exists, and otherwise just shows everything else.

I tried to create a view first in the code, then to do `UNION` on it. But it seems like view are only for PL/SQL code.

I also tried the outer joins, but this doesn't work.

I think the problem may  be in the `WHERE` condition of my join code. I did like Dmitri suggest belwo :

```
 AND nvl(sodRow.activity_result_code, 'ASD') = 'ASD'
 AND nvl(configRow.activity_result_code, 'ACL') = 'ACL'
```

or also alternatively :
problem is that it won't return any rows. I.E If we're looking for 'ACL' then the previous check of 'ASD' becomes true and will render the next check useless.

I think I'm just having trouble visualizing how the joins work here

, thanks !

Comment: By any chance, could this be reduced to some _simple_ case focusing _only_ on your issue ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux  - I pared it down now a little

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try left outer join

```
  left outer join hhs_umx_resp_activity sodRow  ON sodRow.reg_request_id = approvedRow.reg_request_id
```

and nvl

```
  AND nvl(sodRow.activity_result_code, 'ASD') = 'ASD'
```

it will return records with null in sodRow.activity_result_code or 'ASD' in it

Comment: Do you mean the `AND nvl(sodRow.activity_result_code, 'ASD') = 'ASD'` code come after  the join  ... I tried and this  didn't work

Comment: with left outer join?

Comment: correct, the joining doesn't seem to work. but i;ll look again

Comment: oops , misunderstood you there. 1 sec

Comment: He means that instead of writing 'join hhs_umx_resp_activity sodRow  ON sodRow.reg_request_id = approvedRow.reg_request_id` you need to write `left outer join hhs_umx_resp_activity sodRow  ON sodRow.reg_request_id = approvedRow.reg_request_id`. Try that and see if it corrects your issue.

Comment: @BobJarvis - Ok, I tried that .. and it still won't work. not sure

Comment: Did you also update the code in the `WHERE` clause as @DmitryAgibov shows in his second code block above? In other words, you need to replace `AND sodRow.activity_result_code = 'ASD'` with `AND nvl(sodRow.activity_result_code, 'ASD') = 'ASD'` in the WHERE clause of your original query.

Comment: @BobJarvis - what could be the issue here ? does Oracle ever give you invalid error msg's - like it may say "invalid identifier" hwen it's really another issue altogether ?

Comment: Wait, that code is somewhat strange I think ... I mean the second part `nvl(sodRow.activity_result_code, 'ASD') = 'ASD'` ?!??!

Comment: the reason I say so, is because I have another column which could be null (called 'ACV' ) --- so if I put two `1 = 1` rows after each other... isn't that incorrect cod ehere?

Comment: @DmitryAgibov -  I think I'm getting closer here, I tried `NVL(configRow.ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE, 'ACV') IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Testing some more thi ngs